# Geographically display item with highest score by country - Tableau

Tags: maps, tableau-api

I have data in the following format:

```
Type       |    Country     | Item   | Value
Category A |    Afghanistan | Item 1 |  5
Category A |    Afghanistan | Item 2 |  3
Category A |    Afghanistan | Item 3 |  1
Category B |    Afghanistan | Item 1 |  2
Category B |    Afghanistan | Item 2 |  5
Category B |    Afghanistan | Item 3 |  1
```

I'm trying to create a map of country values, such that:

- Each country is colored depending on which item received the highest cumulative value (in this case, if Item 1 is red, 2 is blue, and 3 is green, Afghanistan would be colored blue)
- The item with the highest cumulative value is displayed when hovering over the country

I know that I could just manually calculate it on my own end, but I want to introduce additional filters to the file so that you could, for example, exclude Category A or B and have it recalculate the top value item.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a Max value calculation using the Fixed syntax: `{FIXED [Country] : max([Value])}`

   2. Drag that column into the Dimensions area
   3. Place that calculated field on the color marker shelf

Comment: Hi RHC1. Thanks for posting! This formula gives the max individual value for each country, so in this case it yields "5" for Afghanistan.

I want to create a field for the item with the highest score. So it should be an item, not a value. Does that make sense?